# PHP script via cron is not finding files called in the code

Tags: cron, cron-task

I want to run php script that is located on server at:

```
/var/www/my_directory/myfile.php
```

Script executes one function that uses certificate files located at:

```
/var/www/my_directory/my_cert_dir/cert_file.pem
```

inside PHP script they look like this:

```
$key="my_cert_dir/cert_file.pem";
```

I have also tried to add `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`:

```
$key=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/my_cert_dir/cert_file.pem";
```

In both cases I get "file not found" for my certificate files.
However, when run through CLI or browser they execute without problems.

First I used cron like this:

```
13 19 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/my_directory/myfile.php >> /var/www/my_directory/my_logs_dir/some_log.txt
```

And cron executed the script and I got errors, so I tried to change cron to execute from directory like this:

```
13 19 * * * cd /var/www/my_directory; /usr/bin/php myfile.php >> /var/www/my_directory/my_logs_dir/some_log.txt
```

However this time I don't see that script executes and my log is not created.

**Any ideas how to fix my issue so that script is executed and cert files are found?**

Comment: Why not try the full path `$key="/var/www/my_directory/my_cert_dir/cert_file.pem";` in the php script?

Comment: @Roadowl Thank you  simple and effective for my case. If you write an answer I will mark you as solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try the full path:

`$key="/var/www/my_directory/my_cert_dir/cert_file.pem"`